# Force function inline in LLVM

Tags: fortran, llvm, clang++, llvm-ir, flang

I have a function written in fortran:

```
!function.f90
subroutine ffunc(i, x)
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  integer(c_int), value :: i
  integer(c_int) :: x(*)
  x(1) = i
end
```

and c function:

```
extern "C" void cfunction(int i, long* x) {
  x[0] = i;
}

extern "C" void ffunc_(int i, long* x);

extern "C" void bigcall(int i, long* x) {
  ffunc_(i, x);
}
```

my makefile:

```
all:
        flang -O2 -S -emit-llvm ./function.f90
        clang++ -O2 -S -emit-llvm ./cfunction.cpp
        llvm-link -S function.ll cfunction.ll -o all.ll
        opt -S --inline  all.ll -o all_opt.ll
```

I want to translate generate LLVM IR and inline that IR into a C++ function. 
Everything works except I have to add "alwaysinline" attribute to the fortran IR in order for the `opt` step to inline in it.

How do I force generation of inline attribute OR how do I force `opt` to inline function without the attribute present?